# How would I transfer selected listview item to another listview

Tags: android, listviewitem

I have so far managed the hard bit of selecting the Data I want from my ListView and opening the next activity with the following code.

```
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, 
             int position, long id) {
           // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
           Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);



           String playerName = 
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Player_Name"));
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
             playerName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           Intent in = new Intent(context, PlayerStatsActivity.class);
           in.putExtra ("Name", playerName);
           startActivity(in);
         finish();
           }
      });
```

PlayerStatsActivity Class

```
 public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.statseditor);
     dbHelper = new PlayerStatsDatabase(this);
      dbHelper.open();
     Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
     if(extras !=null){
         String value = extras.getString("Name");
     }
      //Clean all data
    //  dbHelper.deleteAllStats();
      //Add some data
      //dbHelper.insertSomeCountries();

      //Generate ListView from SQLite Database
      //displayListView();
    // list = getListView();
     String PlayerNameText = extras.getString("Name");
     btnSave2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSaveStats);
     btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClearStats);
    txtGoalsScored = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtGoal);
    txtMinutesPlayed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMinPlayed);
    txtSubstituteIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSubIn);
    txtSubstituteOut = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSubOut);
    radioSubIn = (RadioButton) findViewById (R.id.rdoSubIn);
    radioSubOut = (RadioButton) findViewById (R.id.rdoSubOut);
    playerRating = (RatingBar) findViewById (R.id.ratingBar1);
    playerName = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1);
    playerName.setText(PlayerNameText);
```

I want the `playerName` String selected from the previous activity to be displayed in the `playerName TextView`. Above is what i tried but `PlayerNameText` returns null value.

I already have

```
     String value = extras.getString("name");
     }
```

which should get my playerName String I just need to call this to my playerName textfeild I think but can't figure how.

Comment: Log the value of playerName in setOnItemClickListener to see if it is empty or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first activity you are setting

> in.putExtra ("Name", playerName);

while in the other activity you are trying to access

> String value = extras.getString("name");

In one name starts with capital N and in other with same. make them both same.

Edit II:

Try this before in.putExtra ("Name", playerName); to see if you are saving value or not. Then see in log that you are saying Player name, not just null.

Log.d("TAG", "Value: "+ playerName);

Comment: I realised this after I had posted it, changed it and tried it still nothing. I should update the code.

Comment: You can try debug or just use Log to see if value is being saved or not.

Comment: Tried it, log is empty... weird.

Comment: so the problem is that playerName is empty. Try in.putExtra ("Name", "Some name"); to make sure this will show "Some Name" in next Activity. You have to find out why playerName is empty.

Comment: I tried this with no results. Is my stringName not getting saved?